# Active UI navigation on the view under popover

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, scenekit

I have an UI where the SCNView is in the background, and a WKWebView is in the foreground presented as a `.popover`. Views are controlled by separate view controllers. The WKWebView appears when user presses the *bell button* (see the attached screen). SCNView has standard camera control enabled.

Currently when the WKWebView popover appears the SCNView becomes unresponsive. Tap gesture outside the WKWebView closes it, other gestures are ignored, so user cannot control SCNView camera while WKWebView popover is visible. **How can I make the SCNView responsive while WKWebVIew popover is present? How can I dismiss the WKWebView only when the *bell button* is pressed?**

[image: App view - WKWebView in the front makes SCNView in the back unresponsive. How can I control SCNView camera while WKWebView is present?]

Code used below:

```
class MainVC: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var scnView: SCNView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bellBtn: UIButton!
    var myWebViewVC: MyWebViewVC!    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/DemoScene.scn")!
        let scnView = sceneView
        scnView!.scene = scene
        scnView!.allowsCameraControl = true
    }
    @IBAction func onBellBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        myWebViewVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        myWebViewVC.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
        present(myWebViewVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        myWebViewVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender
        myWebViewVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sender.bounds
    }
}
```

The `MyWebViewVC` takes care only of the size of the view. No additional custom modifications are implemented in the file.

Comment: I don't work with SceneKit, but this seems more iOS-related, as in (1) how a standard popover works and (2) how UI-related processing needs to be in the main thread. In the former, you *might* get around this by creating your own popover - it may need to be a full screen view that "looks" like a popover. Something where you have full control on the screen in areas that are not part of the popover. In the latter? I'm not sure you can do anything, unless you can do some automated sort of animation (and that may not be possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So the solution is mainly connected with the `popoverPresentationController` parameter of the view controller. Here is [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621428-popoverpresentationcontroller). To enable control on the view beneath the view presented as a `.popover` you need to inform it about the views which are going to be responsive when popover is present. The order of the passing is top to bottom. The code below and the `passThrough` array make it work.

```
class MainVC: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var scnView: SCNView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bellBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var dotBtn: UIButton!
    var myWebViewVC: MyWebViewVC!    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/DemoScene.scn")!
        scnView!.scene = scene
        scnView!.allowsCameraControl = true
    }
    @IBAction func onBellBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        activeUiNavigationUnderPopover()
    }
    func activeUiNavigationUnderPopover () {
        myWebViewVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        myWebViewVC.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
        if let pop = myWebViewVC.popoverPresentationController {

                var passthroughViews: [AnyObject]?
                    passthroughViews = [dotBtn, scnView]
                    pop.passthroughViews = NSMutableArray(array: passthroughViews!) as? [UIView]
                    pop.permittedArrowDirections = .any
                    pop.delegate = self
        }
        present(myWebViewVC, animated: true, completion: nil) 
        myWebViewVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender
        myWebViewVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sender.bounds
    }
}
```